# how to increase the "soft memory limit" for google app engine beyond 2gb

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memory, google-cloud-platform

I am exceeding the soft memory limit in google app engine (4 to 6 gb, soft limit is set at 2gb) by using this app yaml file:

```
runtime: python37
service: snow
instance_class: F4_1G
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 16
  disk_size_gb: 20
```

It appears the resources memory_gb is not related to the "soft limit" memory. When booting up my app, I need to train an ML model that takes around 4 to 6gb memory. Is there any other way to increase the memory during app deployment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you are trying to configure resource settings in App Engine Standard.  The resources section is only configurable in App Engine Flexible [1]. I suggest adding `env: flex` in the app.yaml for it to take into effect.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#resource-settings

Comment: Note that app engine flex has a lot of differences from app engine standard so you'll likely need to do more than just add `env: flex` to your `app.yaml`.  But the advice is correct that you can't get more than 2gb memory with app engine standard.