# App Engine for cloud monitoring metrics throwing 500 error when writing to big query

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-monitoring

I want to export Metrics from Cloud Monitoring to Big Query and google has given a solution on how to do this. I am following this [this](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/stackdriver-monitoring-metric-export) article.

I have downloaded the code from [github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/stackdriver-metrics-export) and I am able to successfully deploy and run the application (python2.7),

I have given the aggregate alignment period as **86400s** (I want to aggregate metrics per day starting from 1st July)
One of the app-engines the write-metrics app engine which writes the metrics to the big query, by getting the api response as a pub-sub message is always throwing me these errors:

**> Exceeded soft memory limit of 256 MB with 270 MB after servicing 5 requests total. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.**

**> While handling this request, the process that handled this request was found to be using too much memory and was terminated. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may have a memory leak in your application or may be using an instance with insufficient memory. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.**

The above is 500 error and very frequent and I find that duplicate records are getting inserted in the table in BigQuery still
and also this one below

> DeadlineExceededError: The overall deadline for responding to the HTTP request was exceeded.

The app engine logs frequently show POST with codes 500 and 200

[image]

In app engine(**standard**) I have added the scaling as **automatic** and set in app.yaml as below:

```
automatic_scaling:
  target_cpu_utilization: 0.65
  min_instances: 5
  max_instances: 25
  min_pending_latency: 30ms
  max_pending_latency: automatic
  max_concurrent_requests: 50
```

but this seems to have no effect. I am very new to app engine,google-cloud and its stackdriver metrics.

Comment: Stupid question, but have you tried increasing the instance class in app.yaml? Does your app.yaml have such a field?

Comment: Seems, like you need to use AppEngine Flex in order to change the soft Memory limit https://stackoverflow.com/a/57470956/946789

Comment: @NicholasElkaim i have tried instance_class but that field is not getting accepted as a legal identifier

Comment: the instance_class works i should have put in the correct place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This change makes it work

```
instance_class: F4_1G
```

This needs to be as a independent tag and previously i had made the mistake of putting under the `automatic scaling:` so it gave illegal modifier