# GCC App Engine standard enviroment in Django memory usage fails

Tags: google-app-engine, gcc, memory, memory-leaks

From 1 month ago I am experiencing a memory problem in my django app. It is in GCC in GAE + SQL Postgress DB. Apparently I did not modify anything relevant from a memory consumption point of view, getting the error randomly all along the requests.

The error I got is this:

*While handling this request, the process that handled this request was found to be using too much memory and was terminated. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may have a memory leak in your application or may be using an instance with insufficient memory. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.*

I am wondering how can I identify the source of this error. Increasing instante minimum type of course decreased the number of errors but they are still present. I do not think my app needs a lot of memory anyway.

Can anybody help me? What can I do?

Thanks,

Pablo

Comment: Did you make any change in your code at all? One way to try to debug the issue is to go to log explorer (on cloud console), select an entry, click on the duration (the figure showing how long the request took) and it will display a drop down menu. Then select ```view trace details```. This will give you a breakdown of the calls that were made and how long each call took (plus other data)

Comment: No way to solve this. Of course if I increase the instance type the frequence of the problem is smaller. It seems like there is a request that tries to enter memory but does not fit because it is almost full. The bigger the memory, there are less times the memory is almost full but in the end you reach the 99% and the next request overflows and gives 500 error... No idea what to do...

Comment: if target_memory_utilization could be set in appyalm, it could fix my problem... (sorry for the double comment)

Answer (score 1):

As per the error message,

> While handling this request, the process that handled this request was found to be using too much memory and was terminated. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may have a memory leak in your application or may be using an instance with insufficient memory. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.

It seems like the requests are utilizing too much memory which causes the insufficient memory.

To mitigate this issue, I would suggest to cross check the below options:

1. Use a larger [instance class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard#instance_classes) or upgrade an instance class with more memory based on your application workload, which may help you to resolve this issue.
2. Also make sure the app is catching the SIGTERM signal. If not, the instance is immediately shut down. This was stated in the public [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/how-instances-are-managed#shutdown).
3. To reduce the chunks of data you process in each request. You could split it to smaller pieces and keep the smaller instance doing the work.
4. Also have a look at this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57469842/18265702), as you are trying to configure resource settings in App Engine Standard. The resources section is only configurable in [App Engine Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#resource-settings). It is suggested adding `env: flex` in the `app.yaml` for it to take into effect.

There might be the possibility the error occurs due to a change in the code and try to debug the issue by following the steps provided by @NocommandLine in the Comment section. If the above steps don't help, you may consider contacting [Google support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) as it may require project inspection.